# Carrying a parent element's controller into an HTML template that is inserted into a directive's template via ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

I've created an angular directive with a template similar to this:

```
<div>
  <header class='header'></header>
  <div class='subheader'>
    <div ng-bind-html='subheaderTemplate'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='content' ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

This directive will always be used within a parent div that has a controller on it. Each usage of the directive will pass in a different HTML snippet as the subheaderTemplate, from the parent controller. Some instances need this HTML snippet to use the controller from the parent container. But testing it out, the subheader template doesn't seem to know about the parent controller at all.

Here's a typical usage of the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
  <my-directive subheader-template="mc.subheaderTemplate">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </my-directive>
</div>
```

Am I misunderstanding some behavior from ng-bind-html or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are after and I think I got it to work in this plunker based on the example in the Angular docs. So it should work. Maybe you can provide more code if this example does not solve your problem.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.header = '<h1>I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em></h1>';
  }])
  .directive('test', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div><header class='header'></header><div class='subheader'><div ng-bind-html='subheaderTemplate'></div></div><div class='content' ng-transclude></div></div>", 
        scope: {
          subheaderTemplate: '='
        },
        transclude: true
      }
  });
  
  
  
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example62-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
 <test subheader-template="header">
   <h3>subheader</h3>
 </test>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywbvYRvAMuMQBpvbvDnh?p=preview)

Comment: Not quite. The subheader template is defined in a separate controller, and passed into the directive I've created and used in the ng-bind-html attribute of a div in the directive template. That subheader template needs to be able to access the outer controller's scope, which it doesn't seem to be able to do.

Comment: So you want to use scope variables from the controller (mc in your example) in the subheader-template. Thats not possible from what I know.